# ¿Cómo actualizar UI o método después de unos segundos?

Tags: android

Tengo una actividad con un botón y 2 `ImageView`, estoy buscando la forma de que al pulsar el botón se cargue una imagen en un `ImageView` y un segundo mas tarde se cargue otra imagen en el otro `ImageView`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Esto lo puedes lograr mediante un [Handler](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html), tu boton llamaría el método `cargaImagenes()` , el cual dentro contiene métodos para cargar la 2 imágenes, secuencialmente con un intervalo de 1 segundo.

```
private void cargaImagenes(){
    cargaPrimerImagen();
    new Handler().postDelayed( new Runnable(){
        public void run(){
            cargaSegundaImagen();
        }
    }, 1000); //1000 millisegundos después llama método cargaSegundaImagen();
}
```

---

Mediante un [handler](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html) puedes llamar la ejecución de un método despues de n segundos

```
 new Handler().postDelayed( new Runnable(){
        public void run(){

           myMetodo();

        }
    }, 5000); //5000 millisegundos = 5 segundos, para ejecutar myMetodo().
```