# ¿ Cómo ejecutar un dialogo modal que se cierre automáticamente después de 10 segundos?

Tags: java, android, timer

Tengo lo siguiente dentro del método `onCreate()` y necesariamente debe estar ahí:

`do {`

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
builder.setTitle(R.string.contacto).setIcon(R.drawable.rudeboys_icon);
builder.setMessage("hola");
builder.show(); } while(timer_dialog<10);
```

El cual muestra un dialog con el texto "hola" y mi timer_dialog que será mi tiempo de 10 segundos, pero en el onCreate no sé ponerlo.

En una función sé que es algo como :

`timer = new CountDownTimer(tiempo_dialog * 1000, 1000) {`

```
        @Override
        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
            crono.setText("" + String.format(FORMAT, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toHours(millisUntilFinished),
                    TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(millisUntilFinished) - TimeUnit.HOURS.toMinutes(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toHours(millisUntilFinished)),
                    TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(millisUntilFinished) - TimeUnit.MINUTES.toSeconds(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(millisUntilFinished))));


        }
        @Override
        public void onFinish() { //finalizar dialog } }
```

¿ Cómo lo puedo hacer ? He puesto un do-while , es lo más eficiente?

Comment: Hay algo que no me suelta - porque dices que tu tienes que crear el dialogo en `onCreate`? Me entra la sospecha que estas haciendo algo feo. Usas el dialogo para esperar hasta que tu `Activity` genera/busca los datos?

Comment: Te sugiero revisar en el sitio si existen preguntas similares: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/13160/c%C3%B3mo-actualizar-ui-despu%C3%A9s-de-unos-segundos

Answer (score 3, accepted):

El Builder es solamente para construir el dialogo. Comprobrar si se muestra o descartarlo tienes que hacer en el dialogo

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
builder.setTitle(R.string.contacto).setIcon(R.drawable.rudeboys_icon);
builder.setMessage("hola");
final AlertDialog mDialog = builder.create();
// para hacerlo modal
mDialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
mDialog.show();
```

En tu código creas 10 diálogos en un `while`. Mejor cierra el dialogo con un `Handler` después del tiempo.

El Handler:

```
new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            if(null != mDialog && mDialog.isShowing()) mDialog.dismiss();
        }
    }, 10000);
```

Comment: Stefan, sí, es así, gracias, lo que pasa que pensaba que no se me cerraría si toco la pantalla pero no es así, si toco fuera del dialog se me cierra y no quiero, tiene solución?

Comment: Por eso buscaba a lo mejor un timer en vez de un handler, pero yo pensaba que el handler me lo bloqueaba también :(

Comment: Vale, he puesto ``builder.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);`` pero me sale en rojo lo de "setCanceled..." , es porque estoy en fragment o por qué?

Answer (score 2):

```
new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                if(builder != null && builder.isShowing()) builder.dismiss();
            }
        }, 10000);
```

Agregas un Handler para que luego de 10 segundos se cierre.

Comment: Sí, sabía lo del handler pero, me da error en "builder" ¿ si es dialog qué se pone en vez de esa palabra?

Comment: Obvio q va después, en todo caso necesito saber el error de tu consola

Comment: no ,no es error de consola, si , si que es despues, por eso lo borré, me refiero, que estoy poniendo "dialog" en vez de "builder" y me sale en rojo también.

Comment: me sale builder en rojo diciendo: **Variable 'builder' is accessed from within inner class, needs to be declared final**

Comment: tienes que declarar tu `Alert.Dialog` con `final`, entonces sólo debes agregar `final` al comienzo.. `final AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());`

Comment: Y he puesto  ``final AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());`` pero me sale entonces el ``.isShowing()`` y ``.dismiss`` en rojo

Comment: Sí marlon, comenté al mismo tiempo, pero me sale lo que dije en rojo ahora.

Comment: Entonces sólo tienes error de sintaxis ? Por que esto me funciona a mí de maravillas.

Comment: Si, sintaxis, estoy en un fragment que se me ha olvidado comentar...

Answer (score 1):

Puedes usar un handler:
[¿Cómo actualizar UI o método después de unos segundos?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/13160/c%C3%B3mo-actualizar-ui-despu%C3%A9s-de-unos-segundos/13161#13161)

ejemplo, si deseas llamar algún método después de 10 segundos:

```
new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {

            //Llama método deseado.

            }
        }, 10000);
```

---

Primeramente tu creas el díalogo y lo muestras, cuando esta creado el díalogo puedes crear un handler que llame el método `dismiss()` para cerrarlo. Si estas en un Fragment, el contexto a usar se obtendría mediante `getActivity()` :

Ejemplo:

```
    AlertDialog.Builder dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
    dialog.setCancelable(false);
    dialog.setTitle("Dialog & Handler");
    dialog.setMessage("Este dialogo se cerrara en 10 segundos!");
    dialog.setPositiveButton("OK!!!", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
            //No action.
        }
    })
            .setNegativeButton("Cancel ", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                //No action.
                }
            });

    final AlertDialog alert = dialog.create();
    alert.show();  //Muestra dialogo.

    //Crea handler, em 10 segundos cierra el dialogo.
    new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable(){
        public void run(){
            if (alert.isShowing()) {
                alert.dismiss();
            }
        }
    }, 10000); //10 segundos después llama alert.dismiss();
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

---

En cuanto a tu código estas creando y mostrando varios `AlertDialog` mientras que el valor de la variable `timer_dialog` es menor a 10...

```
do {
  AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
  builder.setTitle(R.string.contacto).setIcon(R.drawable.rudeboys_icon);
  builder.setMessage("hola");
  builder.show(); 
} while(timer_dialog<10);
```

**esto es incorrecto**, únicamente debes crear una instancia del `AlertDialog`.

Comment: @RfMvs gracias, perdon pero me ocupe y apenas complete la edición. Pero el ejemplo que pongo realizará lo que deseas que es cerrar tu dialogo después de 10 segundos.

Comment: te doy +1, pero me lo solucionó Stefan hace un rato , pero me guardo esto porque es realmente util lo de cancel y ok, !

Comment: @RfMvs Perfecto, el objetivo es contribuir todos para ayudar en la solución! =)

Comment: Perfecto! si ^^ te has cambiado el nombre? O.O

Answer (score 0):

Para arreglar el problema de que se te cierra la pantalla cuando clickeas afuera, solamente tenes que crear el dialogo asi:

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
  builder.setTitle(R.string.contacto).setIcon(R.drawable.rudeboys_icon);
  builder.setMessage("hola");
  builder.setCancelable(false); // <--- Esta linea agregue.
  builder.show();
```

Saludos.

Comment: Sí, gracias, probé lo que me dijo para ambas respuesta la pregunta marcada como destacada y me funcionó, gracias de todas formas Alan!

Comment: Tengo una pregunta de youtube que de momento nadie ha sabido responder, pásate si puedes por favor.

Answer (score 0):

en mi caso usando un DialogFragment, declare el Dialog como final

antes(sin agregar el timer):

```
BottomSheetEsperaConfirmacionPeticion bottomSheet = new BottomSheetEsperaConfirmacionPeticion();
```

despues:

```
final BottomSheetEsperaConfirmacionPeticion bottomSheet = new BottomSheetEsperaConfirmacionPeticion();
```

despues agregue un Handler para crear el temporizador

```
   new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable(){
                    public void run(){
/*aqui agregas las sentencias que deseas que se ejecuten despues del tiempo transcurrido*/
                        bottomSheet.dismiss();/*en mi caso solo se oculta el Dialog*/
                        }
                    }, 5000);/*temporizador*/
```