# Ejecutar un determinado código después de x segundos

Tags: android, setinterval

Tengo un **app** que muestra una pantalla modal de información, lo que necesito es que al cabo de x segundos se cierre y ejecute el siguiente código:

```
mProgressDialog.dismiss();
Intent intent = new Intent(Registrar2.this, MainActivity.class);
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
startActivity(intent);
finish();
```

Hay alguna función tipo `SetTimeOut` de `JavaScript`¿?

Comment: Tienes esta pregunta en el foro en ingles, puede que te sirva https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13100196/making-a-interval-timer-in-java-android

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Mediante un [handler](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html) puedes llamar la ejecución de un método despues de n segundos, por ejemplo 5 segundos (5000 milisegundos):

```
     new Handler().postDelayed( new Runnable(){
            public void run(){

            //----------------------------         
            mProgressDialog.dismiss();
            Intent intent = new Intent(Registrar2.this, MainActivity.class);
            intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
            intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
            startActivity(intent);
            finish();
            //----------------------------         

            }
        }, 5000); //5000 millisegundos = 5 segundos.
```

Aquí existe otra respuesta:

**[¿Cómo actualizar UI o método después de unos segundos?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/13160/c%C3%B3mo-actualizar-ui-o-m%C3%A9todo-despu%C3%A9s-de-unos-segundos/13161#13161)**

Answer (score -1):

He realizado está solución basándome en [esta respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/46362/45237)

```
 new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        mProgressDialog.dismiss();
        Intent intent = new Intent(Registrar2.this, MainActivity.class);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
        startActivity(intent);
        finish();
    }
}, 5000);
```