# ¿Cómo hacer que una función se ejecute cada 5 o 10 segundos?

Tags: java, android

Bueno mi idea es, una vez que la aplicación inicie me compruebe cada 5 o 10 segundos la conexión de Internet, esto con el fin de que si se pierde la conexión que se me notifique, y cuando se restablezca la conexión todo siga normal.

Comment: Hola Jaron, esto es muy amplio. Por favor, muestra lo que has intentado y si no lo has hecho, investiga un poco e intenta implementarlo. Cuando lo intentes muestranos los problemas concretos que tienes. Un saludo

Comment: Buenas revisa [ask] y [mcve] para que te podamos ayudar mejor.

Comment: voy a replantear la duda.

Comment: Lo que deberias hacer es crear un hilo para que se ejecute con el resto del programa

Comment: por qué quitaste el código ?

Comment: no lo creí necesario para mi consulta.

Comment: Has modificado tu pregunta para dejarla aun peor?

Comment: Ya lo resolví, gracias por su tiempo. Pura vida!!

Comment: Por si al alguien le interesa, utilicé un `TimerTask`

Comment: Intentalo con javax.swing.Timer http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html

Comment: Muchas gracias.

Comment: Mejor usar un BroadcastReceiver del servicio de conectividad a cambio de estar todo el rato comprobando conexión a internet.

Comment: Muchas gracias amigo.

Comment: **Te recomiendo antes de agregar una pregunta, buscar en el sitio**, en este caso se tienen información sobre esto: https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/38222/95

https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/13160/c%C3%B3mo-actualizar-ui-o-m%C3%A9todo-despu%C3%A9s-de-unos-segundos/13161#13161

https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/75003/ejecutar-un-determinado-c%C3%B3digo-despu%C3%A9s-de-x-segundos/75008#75008

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Antes de usar un procedimiento que cada cierto tiempo vaya comprobando, puedes interceptar cuando hay un cambio en la conectividad.

Extraido de [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25873554/3464919)

**interceptor**

Crea un `BroadcastReceiver` para interceptar el cambio.

```
private BroadcastReceiver networkStateReceiver=new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        ConnectivityManager manager = (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        NetworkInfo ni = manager.getActiveNetworkInfo();
        if (ni!= null && ni.isAvailable() && ni.isConnected()) //haz algo con internet
    }
};
```

**Registrar la escucha**

Para poder interceptar debes registrar lo que quieres interceptar, en este caso `android.net.ConnectivityManager.CONNECTIVITY_ACTION`

```
@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    registerReceiver(networkStateReceiver, new IntentFilter(android.net.ConnectivityManager.CONNECTIVITY_ACTION));
}
```

Importante para aliberizar recursos, parar el interceptor, cuando la app no lo requiere.

```
@Override
public void onPause() {
    unregisterReceiver(networkStateReceiver);
    super.onPause();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Si deseas que un metodo se ejecute cada x tiempo puedes utilizar un ScheduledExecutorService

te dejo un ejemplo :

```
//declaramos un ScheduledExecutorService y obtenemos una instancia de el. 

ScheduledExecutorService executor = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();
//agendamos la tarea utilizando una expresion lambda , pasandole el metodo que se debe ejecutar , luego debemos indicar el tiempo que tomara la primera accion ,seguido indicamos el 
//intervalo de tiempo que tomara para repetir la accion,finalmente indicamos la unidad de tiempo.
executor.scheduleAtFixedRate( ()-> {tuMetodo();} , 0, 2, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```